# Git Remote Push Fatal Error

Tags: git, git-push

I am trying to push a rails project to github from my mac terminal.  I keep getting this fatal error message. Earlier today I was working on the same project, but decided to restart it. When I was working on it earlier someone else setup a repository and gave me access to it and I was able to remotely push to that repo. For some reason when I am creating a new repo I'm not able to push to it. I'm not sure how to set the permisson, but when I tried to do it from my GitHub mac app it also did not work. This is the view of my terminal...

```
new-host-5:blogger $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/evankline/Documents/Ruby_Programs/JumpStart/Rails_Blogger/blogger/.git/
new-host-5:blogger evankline$ git add .
new-host-5:blogger evankline$ git commit -m "first blog commit"
[master (root-commit) c4d5702] first blog commit
57 files changed, 867 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 .DS_Store
create mode 100644 .gitignore
create mode 100644 Gemfile
create mode 100644 Gemfile.lock
create mode 100644 README.rdoc
create mode 100644 Rakefile
create mode 100644 app/.DS_Store
create mode 100644 app/assets/.DS_Store
create mode 100644 app/assets/images/.keep
create mode 100644 app/assets/javascripts/application.js
create mode 100644 app/assets/javascripts/articles.js.coffee
create mode 100644 app/assets/stylesheets/.DS_Store
create mode 100644 app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
create mode 100644 app/assets/stylesheets/articles.css.scss
create mode 100644 app/assets/stylesheets/screen.css
create mode 100644 app/controllers/application_controller.rb
create mode 100644 app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
create mode 100644 app/controllers/concerns/.keep
create mode 100644 app/helpers/application_helper.rb
create mode 100644 app/helpers/articles_helper.rb
create mode 100644 app/mailers/.keep
create mode 100644 app/models/.keep
create mode 100644 app/models/article.rb
create mode 100644 app/models/concerns/.keep
create mode 100644 app/views/.DS_Store
create mode 100644 app/views/articles/.DS_Store
create mode 100644 app/views/articles/index.html.erb
create mode 100644 app/views/articles/show.html.erb
create mode 100644 app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
create mode 100644 bin/.DS_Store
create mode 100755 bin/bundle
create mode 100755 bin/rails
create mode 100755 bin/rake
create mode 100644 config.ru
create mode 100644 config/application.rb
create mode 100644 config/boot.rb
create mode 100644 config/database.yml
create mode 100644 config/environment.rb
create mode 100644 config/environments/development.rb
create mode 100644 config/environments/production.rb
create mode 100644 config/environments/test.rb
create mode 100644 config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
create mode 100644 config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
create mode 100644 config/initializers/inflections.rb
create mode 100644 config/initializers/mime_types.rb
create mode 100644 config/initializers/secret_token.rb
create mode 100644 config/initializers/session_store.rb
create mode 100644 config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
create mode 100644 config/locales/en.yml
create mode 100644 config/routes.rb
create mode 100644 db/migrate/20130813003448_create_articles.rb
create mode 100644 db/schema.rb
create mode 100644 db/seeds.rb
create mode 100644 lib/assets/.keep
create mode 100644 lib/tasks/.keep
create mode 100644 log/.keep
create mode 100644 public/404.html
create mode 100644 public/422.html
create mode 100644 public/500.html
create mode 100644 public/favicon.ico
create mode 100644 public/robots.txt
create mode 100644 test/controllers/.keep
create mode 100644 test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb
create mode 100644 test/fixtures/.keep
create mode 100644 test/fixtures/articles.yml
create mode 100644 test/helpers/.keep
create mode 100644 test/helpers/articles_helper_test.rb
create mode 100644 test/integration/.keep
create mode 100644 test/mailers/.keep
create mode 100644 test/models/.keep
create mode 100644 test/models/article_test.rb
create mode 100644 test/test_helper.rb
create mode 100644 vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
create mode 100644 vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
new-host-5:blogger evankline$ git remote add origin git@github.com:emk486/blogger.git
new-host-5:blogger evankline$ git push -u origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Can someone please explain to me how to fix this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That repo doesn't exist in your list of git repos under that spelling.

You have one called "JSLRails_Blogger" but not "blogger"

perhaps try changing your remote line to:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:emk486/JSLRails_Blogger.git
```

Note: you can see the list of repositories you have on git from here:

```
https://github.com/emk486?tab=repositories
```

Comment: The JSRAils_Blogger is the original version I have been working on, but today I restarted the project because of errors in the original. I was hoping to create a new repo for this project. I thought I was creating the repo from the terminal. Do I need to create the repo on github.com first? Also, before I screw up any further, do I need to remove the above add? Thanks!

Comment: I removed the origin, created a new repo named 'blogger', then had another error message telling me my tip was ahead of my branch so I ran git pull --rebase origin master and the push command again and it worked! Thanks for your help Taryn!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. 
The best way to show your thanks is to accept the answer ;)